# Strange behavior in Java with recursivity

Tags: java

I am learning Java. This is my simple java test.

```
import java.io.Console;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Pendu {

    private static final int MAX_ERRORS_ALLOWED = 10;
    private static final int MAX_WORDL_LENGHT = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String motSaisi = Pendu.readMot();
        System.out.println("Le mot saisi est "+motSaisi);
    }

    public static boolean hasSpecialChar (String s) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]");
        return (p.matcher(s).find());
    }

    public static String readMot(){
        char[] ChaineSaisi = System.console().readPassword("Joueur 1 : Veuillez saisir un mot sans chiffres ni lettres accentuées: ");
        String text = String.copyValueOf(ChaineSaisi);
        System.out.println("mot a testé "+text);

        if(Pendu.hasSpecialChar(text)) {
            Pendu.readMot();
        }
        System.out.println("mot correct "+text);
        return text;
    }
}
```

The goal of this is to enter a word witch only characters ( a-Z A-Z) and only this.When i run this with example like this :

```
 Joueur 1 : Veuillez saisir un mot sans chiffres ni lettres accentu?es: 
    mot a test? )))
    Joueur 1 : Veuillez saisir un mot sans chiffres ni lettres accentu?es: 
    mot a test? """
    Joueur 1 : Veuillez saisir un mot sans chiffres ni lettres accentu?es: 
    mot a test? po
    mot correct po
    mot correct """
    mot correct )))
   Le mot saisi est )))
```

")))"  ( This is not the last word i have tpaed, the last is "po"). Why this happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local variables `ChaineSaisi` and `text` are local to each call of `readMot`.  That is, every time `readMot` is called, and these variables are initialised, you're actually getting new instances of these variables.

To do what you want, you'll need to set the `text` value to whatever is returned by the inner call to `readMot`.  If you change the line *inside* the `if` branch to

```
text = Pendu.readMot();
```

then your program should do what you want, because you will then be setting each `text` variable to the value from the later call to `readMot`.

Comment: Thanks, it resolves the problem, but why the last println in the readMot method is called multiple times ( the same time that reaMot is called) ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be called multiple times?  There's no conditional logic around it, so it will be called once in every call to `readMot`.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the recursion. When you first make a recursive call, it will make the current execution process as "pending" so when all the recursion is finished (when there's a special char), it checks the last word typed, then the (n-1)th and so on until it check your very first word.

Anyway, if you just want to check the validity, this is a terrible way of doing it, since you stack your execution pile at each input. Not only it is ugly, but it can create an OutOfMemory exception

Anyway, here's something that should work:

```
while (!StringUtils.isAlpha((input = readString())));
```

StringUtils.isAlpha(myString) returns true is the string is only made of ascii letters.
I suppose that readString() is your read function. Here the program will ask you for an input until it is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. StringUtils is not part of the java.lang and don't want for importing third party library for a sample exercise.

Comment: Oh, this is the right way of doing it.  There is no reason not to import a library from Apache.  The only reason that I provided an answer that was closer in spirit to your original question was that I assumed you were doing this to learn about recursion, not to write production code.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes my code is just for learning purpose. I have accepted your answer because it helped me to fix the recursion problem. The answer of Thuzher helped me also. Thanks for you.